# Regular expression with optional characters at the end

Tags: regex

Right now I have this:
`~(^\/[register]$)~`

Which matches URI `/register`

However, I'm also trying to match URI that has GET variables as well such as `/register?something=google&else=bing`

I'm trying to do something like this, but it's not working.

EDIT: this is what i have so far, it's almost there.
`~^\/(register)\\?(.+)?$~`

Comment: The brackets in `[register]` means to match any of those characters. So `gistersterregstersitter` would match.

Comment: And in addition to @ColeJohnson's comment, the $ means "end of string" (or line), so you can't really match anything in the querystring after that. I don't know what you want to do with the results, but you may want to take a look at [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), that may make your life easier. :)

Comment: OK I changed the initial regex to `~^\/(register)+$~` which should only match /register and not adsadsdregisterasdasdad.

Comment: @zen: What's your final goal? Are you trying to simply check if the URL has `/register` / query parameters in it?

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm trying to return the correct view based on URL request.  And then if the request has GET variables, I want to be able to fetch those as well.  Basically I'm making my own simple mini URL router.  Also, I updated the question with where I am so far.  I almost got it, but not quite there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, you want to match a line that begins with `/register` until the end, checking for optional queries. Also if you are using the delimiter `~`, you can avoid having to escape the `/` here.

```
~^/register\b(\?.*)?$~i
```

If you are trying to capture the optional queries, place a capture group `( )` around `.*`

See [`demo`](http://regex101.com/r/uW0hI5)

Comment: Thanks that's almost there, but I want to check to make sure it has a question mark as well. So that `/register-something` doesn't match but `/register?something` does.

Comment: Also, what does tilde do in this expression?  Is it a delimiter, and if so, how come there's an `i` after it?

Comment: @zen: [`i` flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) is used for case-insensitive matching.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'll mark this one as the answer as it does what I asked. I can take it from here and modify it for other regex expressions I'll need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `$` matches end of pattern, try putting it last.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question with updated regex expressions.